# Convert json String to java object

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have the following jsonString,I need to convert it to java object, I have used the following code to convert it but i get this exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class com.innvo.web.rest.dto.Responsedetail$Questiongroup]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

Json String

```
String jsonStrings ="{"questiongroups":[{"questiongroup":"1000","questions":[{"question":1001,"response":4},{"question":1002,"subquestion":1001,"response":"A2"}]}]}";
```

ResponseDetails.java

```
public class Responsedetail {

@JsonProperty("questiongroups")
public List<Questiongroup> questiongroups;

public List<Questiongroup> getQuestiongroups() {
    return questiongroups;
}

public void setQuestiongroups(List<Questiongroup> questiongroups) {
    this.questiongroups = questiongroups;
}

public Responsedetail() {
    super();
}



class Questiongroup{

    @JsonProperty("questiongroup")
    String questiongroup;
    @JsonProperty("questions")
    List<Question> questions;

    public Questiongroup() {
        super();
    }

    public String getQuestiongroup() {
        return questiongroup;
    }

    public void setQuestiongroup(String questiongroup) {
        this.questiongroup = questiongroup;
    }

    public List<Question> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    class Question{

        @JsonProperty("question")
        String question;
        @JsonProperty("response")
        String response;
        public Question() {
            super();
        }
        public String getQuestion() {
            return question;
        }
        public void setQuestion(String question) {
            this.question = question;
        }
        public String getResponse() {
            return response;
        }
        public void setResponse(String response) {
            this.response = response;
        }       
    }
}
```

}

converting code

```
String jsonStrings ="{"questiongroups":[{"questiongroup":"1000","questions":[{"question":1001,"response":4},{"question":1002,"subquestion":1001,"response":"A2"}]}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Responsedetail responsedetail = mapper.readValue(response.getDetails(), Responsedetail.class);

    System.out.println(responsedetail);
    System.out.println(responsedetail.questiongroups);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Questiongroup` class is nested inside the `Responsedetail` class, and `Question` is nested inside `Questiongroup`.

Since you didn't make them `static`, they are *[inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)*.

Add `static` to the nested classes to make them *static nested classes*.

Alternatively, make them all top-level classes in their own `.java` source files.

Comment: Thanks ,You helped me and save my time